# IntelliJ Constructor definido, pero marca error

Tags: java

Me he econtrado con el siguiente problema, que me esta confundiendo. Ha creado una clase, con un constructor, pero intelliJ dice que no esta definido.

---

> Clase [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

> Constructor
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, por favor revisa [ask]. Recuerda que es preferible el código en formato texto antes que imágenes. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta, puedes hacer clic en [edit]. Saludos

Comment: Por favor agrega el código como texto, te aseguro obtendrìas la ayuda deseada, yo en mi caso tengo bloqueados los dominios donde obtiene las imagenes, no las puedo ver!.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que puedo ver en la clase `Load.java` no esta referenciando al `Main` del proyecto sino `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main`. Por ello el IDE le esta solicitando un constructor con el `Main` del proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

1. Puede que necesites crear un constructor vacío en tu clase `Load`.
2. Revisa el tipo de dato que esta retornando el metodo `getDataFolder`
3. Si ya tienes declarada la variable `dataFolder`  ¿Por que no utilizas esa variable para pasarla como parámetro?
4. Por ultimo, tengo duda si esta bien la sintaxis de `main:this`

Comment: 1. Si creo una clase load. ¿Como puedo pasar variables?
2. Es de tipo File()
3. Eso estoy haciendo en el ejemplo ¿No?
4. Main:this, se refiere a la clase de MAIN

Comment: muestra tu clase Load porfa ... creo que ahi hace falta un contructor que acepte los parametros que estas mandando

Comment: La clase Load, esta en la primera imagen